# "Django_celery_beat" executes task only once

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to integrate django_celery_beat in project.
When I setup task using django admin panel, entries in database are reflected correctly and when I start project task gets executed successfully. however on every successive attempt of sending task after first execution is rather failed or either message is not sent to broker.

My setup :

```
django_celery_beat : 1.0.1
celery: 4.0.1
```

Setting in celeryconfig:

```
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import tempfile
import time
from buy import constants as buy_constants


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))



# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

ADMIN_SITE_ENABLED = False
WAIT_BETWEEN_RATING = 7 # In days
WAIT_BETWEEN_EMAIL_VERIFY = 30 # In minutes
WAIT_BETWEEN_RECOMMENDATIONS = 1 # In minutes
WAIT_BETWEEN_CONNECTION_UPDATE = 60*24*5 # In minutes
SITEMAP_CACHE = 86400


DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (('Pooja Shete', 'pooja.shete@gmail.com'),)


MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"


# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
        )



# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'require.storage.OptimizedCachedStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
        'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
        #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
        )

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'c28yui+jyipz5prse%!o^u_e06$!*_daps8b9+km_aa51f=i%='

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
        )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'logs.middleware.ContextMiddleware',
        'middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
        # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
        # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        )
DJANGO_CONTEXT_LOGGING_EXTRACTOR = lambda request: {}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10
}



# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
        )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'billing',
    'django_user_agents',
    'pipeline',
    'celery',
    'django_celery_beat',
)


SITE_ID = 1


import django.db.models.options as options
options.DEFAULT_NAMES = options.DEFAULT_NAMES + ('db_name',)



SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.request',"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"django.core.context_processors.csrf",
)



PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True

PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
)
PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY = '/usr/local/bin/yuglify'



PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.uglifyjs.UglifyJSCompressor'

PIPELINE_CLOSURE_ARGUMENTS = '--compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY'

PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'

CACHES = {}


# Change this value in local_config as per requirement to use dummy paypal
DUMMY_PAYPAL = False


#  Initialize cached object
##############################

try:
    INITIALIZE_FILE_CACHE
except NameError:
    try:
        from django.core.cache import get_cache
        cache = get_cache('redis_cache')
        try:
            wp = cache.get('word_parser', None)
        except:
            wp = None
        if not wp:
            from bin.cron.wordparser import WordParser
            wp = WordParser()
            cache.set('word_parser', wp, timeout=None)
    except ImportError:
        pass


gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
             ('en', gettext('English')),
             ('fr', gettext('French')),
             ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
             ('ja_JP', gettext('Japanese')),
)

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../locale'),

)
```

Command used to start celerybeat:

```
celery beat -A app-S django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler --loglevel=INFO
```

command used to start workers :

```
celery worker -A app--loglevel=INFO
```

When I start celery I do get exception of :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/worker/pidbox.py", line 42, in on_message
    self.node.handle_message(body, message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 129, in handle_message
    return self.dispatch(**body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 112, in dispatch
    ticket=ticket)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 135, in reply
    serializer=self.mailbox.serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 265, in _publish_reply
    **opts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 203, in _publish
    mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1748, in _basic_publish
    (0, exchange, routing_key, mandatory, immediate), msg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 64, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 174, in write_frame
    write(view[:offset])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 269, in write
    self._write(s)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Logs in beat.stderr.log:

```
[2017-06-12 05:40:00,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task pooja_task (app.tasks.send_test_mail)
[2017-06-12 05:41:00,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task pooja_task (app.tasks.send_test_mail)
[2017-06-12 05:41:00,002: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task pooja_task (app.tasks.send_test_mail)
```

However from all above task sent, celery picks only first task and execute whenever I start by server. All other messages are avoided.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: can you show your beat configuration from settings.py ?

Comment: @sebb I have pasted my settings.py in question